# number of irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory

Prove that if $H$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$ then each irreducible representation of $G$ has degree at most $\frac{|G|}{|H|}$

One proof is given in serre, but I would like to see some different proofs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what Serre's proof is but here's one way: Let $M$ be a simple $G$-module over a field $k$.  You want to show that $\dim M \leq |G|/|H|$.

As simple $H$-modules are one dimensional (cause $H$ is abelian) there is a nonzero $m \in M$ such that $H\cdot m \subseteq km$.  Then $kG\cdot m$ has dimension at most $|G|/|H|$.  But $M$ is a simple $G$-module so $kG\cdot m = M$.